# Acidification of a vicinal diol

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, phenols, rearrangements

The following is a question from *Advanced problems in organic chemistry by MS Chouhan*:

> [image]

The options given are:

> [image]

My initial thought was that this could be a [pinacol–pinacolone rearrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinacol_rearrangement#:%7E:text=The%20pinacol%E2%80%93pinacolone%20rearrangement%20is,rearrangement%20of%20pinacol%20to%20pinacolone.). However the aryl shift would lead to an absurd amount of crowding, and there is no option that corresponds to this.

Secondly, it could form an epoxide, but I'm unsure of that as well.

Any explanation/reference to this reaction is appreciated!

Comment: b and d can be discarded as products immediately. Which aryl group is the more electron-rich and thus the more likely to capture a cation?

Comment: @Waylander it would be the anisole ;-)

Comment: So, I think we're agreed that the answer is either (a) or (c). I got most of the way to the mechanism by trying to map the product onto the starting material (the connectivity really changed!) to determine a likely intermediate. Due to the almost-symmetry, there are two mechanisms at play, but the more likely situation now depends on evaluating the two-step mechanism for what the RDS is...

Comment: @Zhe what were the two mechanisms that you tried? We could try building on it!

Comment: The diol is nearly symmetric. Since the first step is almost certainly protonation of one of the alcohol groups, that's the dichotomy. Then you can have cation formation followed by cyclopropane ring opening + ketone formation; or, doing all of that in a concerted manner. Finally vinylogous attack on the ketone with one of the aryl rings.

Comment: It's a neat mechanism. I wouldn't necessarily have predicted a cyclopentane as a product a priori, but that's what you get when you put a string-loaded cyclopropane in your starting material.

Comment: @Zhe: This question is a duplicate: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124940/is-pinacol-rearrangement-the-source-for-the-ring-expansion/124955#124955

Comment: Steo 1 should be cyclopropane ring collapse, after protonation to give alkene and ketone. Step 2:  Protonation of alkene keading to stable tertiary carbocation. Step 3 : carbocation as electrophile attacks benzene ring(ekectrophillic aromatic substitution).

Comment: This reaction is based on cyclopropane ring collapse forming allyl carbocation.

Comment: @user55119 Excellent answer and a very very interesting mechanism, especially, a pi-bond formation by pinacol rearrangement! I suppose the instability of the ring is the driving force.

Comment: @ChakravarthyKalyan your step 2 does not go along with user55119's mechanism, but I suppose that tautomerizing the ketone would lead to a similar product anyway.

Comment: Step2 is collapse of cyclopropane ring to enol vs allyl alcohol carbocation. In either cases ketone is formed.